# Link to open a PDF file that's saved in a folder?

Tags: c#, html, pdf, hyperlink

Hi there. I think this one is a tough one, but I hope someone can help.

I have a folder which is downloaded from my website. The folder contains a Main PDF report on a housing property, and another folder containing pictures and more PDF reports on similar houses in the area.

On my main PDF report I would like to have a link to open the other PDF folders.

How would I go about creating a link to open a PDF report saved in a file?

Looking at the picture below, where it says CS1.pdf, that is the name of the PDF and where the link will be. This is a screen shot of a portion of my main PDF.

I don't mind if the PDF reports are opened in a webpage, in fact I would prefer it. But, at the moment, I just need a simple link created that will open a PDF located in a folder.

[image: Screenshot of detail from from a PDF]

---

An explanation of the app flow:

Here below I save the PDF that I want to link to later. It's saved to a temp location; the exact location is not important as it will be deleted after the file uploads.

The file I upload contains a few pictures, some PDFs and a data.XML file. When a person downloads the file, the data.XML file is used to create my main PDF, or report, in any format. I need to send a link through the XML file that will appear on the report making it able to link to the other PDF files that were uploaded with the data.xml file.

```
CS1[12].TagValue = ReportDS.Tables[9].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();

//Save PDF
//PDFName = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf";
string PDFName = "CS1" + ".pdf";
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(CS1[12].TagValue, "C://Users//Shaun//Documents//FormValue//" + PDFName);
CS1[12].TagValue = PDFName; //This is the value passed to the main PDF so this is where i should pass the link through.
```

The line `CS1[12].TagValue = PDFName;` is where I set the value to send though to the main PDF, and this is where my link should be sent through.

I need something like `CS1[12].TagValue = "http://C://Users//Shaun//Downloads//CS1.pdf";` but with the file path of the downloaded location.

Comment: As I understand - link should be in report file itself. It is possible to link one PDF file to another, but you should do that while generating reports.

Comment: Yes the link should be in the main report, like where the picture says LightStone Report, the link should be next to that. i'm sure links can open PDF files i just don't know how to open one from a folder.

Comment: The PDF reports i have to link to are all pre saved, but i build the main one though a XML file.

Comment: From what I remember, once you have a link in PDF file which (using HTML notation) looks like this <a href="AnotherPDF.PDF"></a> PDF viewer will search for AnotherPDF.pdf in the same folder where current file is located.

Comment: That sounds promising could you explain a bit more or direct me to a a site where i can go learn more on how to do it?

Comment: And how to add such link depends on how file is created. And I do not think that WebClient may help there somehow.

Comment: The webclient is used to save the pdf files, but i build the main PDF of off a XML file at a later stage, i cant edit the other PDFS can just download them, but need to have a link to them.

Comment: Which tool are you using to create a PDF? Take a look how links are created there. I was working with iTextSharp and now trying to find how it could be done there.

Comment: Is there no way to create the link before the PDF is created? As i Create a XML file and post it up online with all the info i need. At a later stage someone with export this info, mainly in PDF format but it could also be in other formats, so my link needs to be created before i upload the file, and the link is used after the file has been downloaded.

Comment: Just put a link description into your XML. Of course, you should later handle it properly while creating PDF file. For instance, [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/84/iTextSharp-Links-and-Bookmarks) is how link is added in iTextSharp. How that should be done in your case depends on a library you are using to create PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are on a right way but you have some mistake like, when you giving location of pdf file from downloaded location, that must be a file type, its not from a server...

```
CS1[12].TagValue = "http://C://Users//Shaun//Downloads//CS1.pdf";
```

but it must like this

```
CS1[12].TagValue = "file://C://Users//Shaun//Downloads//CS1.pdf";
```

so that you have change one line in your code...

```
webClient.DownloadFile(CS1[12].TagValue, "file://C:/Users//Shaun//Documents//FormValue//" + PDFName);
```